# Typescript drop unknown[] or never?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to make tuple of A and B or only B if A is unknown[] (or alternativately never)

```
type X<A, B> = A extends unknown[] ? [B] : [A, B];
type Y = X<unknown[], {}>; // should be [{}] but isn't
```

variation:

```
type X<A, B> = A extends never ? [B] : [A, B];
type Y = X<never, {}>; // should be [{}] but isn't
```

this only works:

```
type X<A, B> = A extends null ? [B] : [A, B];
type Y = X<null, {}>; // it is [{}]
```

Comment: TS playground says for the first example that everything is ok - https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAGgPAQQDRQEID4oF4oKhAD2AgDsATAZygFcSBrEgewHcSBtAXSgH4o3UuALj7I0HANwAoUJCgBNbLDi0GLdhxQBvAL7pxUAPQGoFABaNqAGzJQARtDY6ut6sCgBLCiQDkwIA

Comment: hi, you are right, but also for type Y = X<['a'], {}>; // it is [{}] :)

Comment: yes because `unknown` is unsound type so almost every type extends it, as unknown can be anything

Comment: The best choice here is `undefined` or `null` as these are sound types

Answer (score 5):

Take a look how `unknown` and `never` types behave in relation to other types:

```
type ExtendsUnknown<X> = X extends unknown ? true : false;
type YesUnknown = ExtendsUnknown<number>; // true
type YesUnknown2 = ExtendsUnknown<object>; // true
type YesUnknown3 = ExtendsUnknown<[number]>; // true
type YesUnknown4 = ExtendsUnknown<unknown>; // true

type ExtendsNever<X> = X extends never ? true : false;
type NoNever = ExtendsNever<number>; // false
type NoNever2 = ExtendsNever<object>; // false
type NoNever3 = ExtendsNever<[number]>; // false
type OhMyGodNever = ExtendsNever<never>; // we get never och man!
```

Types like `any` `never` `unknown` are [unsound types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness). It means that they do not behave in the same way as standard types, they behavior can be against the logic which derives other types. What I mean by this logic is for example:

**if A extends B extends C implies that A extends C**

**if A extends B and B extends A implies A equals B**

above rules are only guaranteed for sound types

That is why for your case, u should use sound types, and I would propose here `undefined` type.

```
// undefined behaves correctly
type ExtendsUndefined<X> = X extends undefined ? true : false;
type NoUndefined = ExtendsUndefined<number>; // false
type NoUndefined2 = ExtendsUndefined<object>; // false
type NoUndefined3 = ExtendsUndefined<number>; // false
type YesUndefined4 = ExtendsUndefined<undefined>; // true - yep that works

type X<A, B> = A extends undefined ? [B] : [A, B];
type Y = X<undefined, {}>;
```